# How to map tickets to seats with Social Tables API

Tags: social-tables

Using the Picatic API and Social Tables API, how can I create an event registration page and render the venue layout and then map a ticket id to a specific seat on the layout?

*The flow would be as follows:*

**Event Manager**

1. Creates a layout on Social Tables
2. Create an event on Picatic
3. Authenticates Social Tables <> Picatic integration
4. Maps tickets to specific seats on their layout

**Ticket Buyer**

1. Visits landing page that displays event layout from Social Tables
2. Selects a seat
3. After selected all tickets they move the checkout process and pay for the ticket(s) through the Picatic API

Are there any widgets, SDKs and/or endpoints that render the Social Tables layout? How can you map ids to a specific seat?

Answer (score 0):

The Social Tables API does not support your use case at this time.